# Why does row 7 only contain zeros?

Tags: r

I'm trying to compile some estimations of a few parameters in a neat matrix. However I keep getting an annoying result.

```
library("spatstat")
ripleysMedian = function(kappa, mu) {
  timesteps = 10
  kappaVector = vector("numeric", timesteps)
  sigmaVector = vector("numeric", timesteps)
  muVector = vector("numeric", timesteps)
  numberOfPoints = vector("numeric", timesteps)

  estimates = matrix(0, nrow = 10, ncol = 4)

  for (sigma in seq(from = 0.01, to = 0.1, by = 0.01)){

    for (i in 1:timesteps) {

      thomasSim = rThomas(kappa = kappa, scale = sigma, mu = mu, win = owin(c(0,1),c(0,1)))

      numberOfPoints[i] = thomasSim[["n"]]

      result = thomas.estK(thomasSim)

      kappaVector[i] = result$modelpar[[1]]
      sigmaVector[i] = result$modelpar[[2]]
      muVector[i] = numberOfPoints[i]/kappaVector[i]

    }

      medianSigma = median(sigmaVector)
      medianKappa = median(kappaVector)
      medianMu = median(muVector)

      print(sigma)
      print(medianKappa)
      print(medianMu)
      print(medianSigma)
      print("************")

      estimates[sigma*100,4] = medianSigma
      estimates[sigma*100,3] = medianMu
      estimates[sigma*100,2] = medianKappa
      estimates[sigma*100,1] = sigma

  }
  return(estimates)
}

ripleysMedian(22.9,4)
```

Which returns the following:

```
   [,1]     [,2]      [,3]       [,4]
 [1,] 0.01 22.94074  4.065733 0.01076195
 [2,] 0.02 29.50798  3.341949 0.01883097
 [3,] 0.03 25.55891  3.205621 0.03209603
 [4,] 0.04 20.59761  3.875839 0.03651481
 [5,] 0.05 18.87119  5.078014 0.05192704
 [6,] 0.07 32.64565  3.464698 0.07300836
 [7,] 0.00  0.00000  0.000000 0.00000000
 [8,] 0.08 20.15657  4.737290 0.10552342
 [9,] 0.09 15.94051 55.657375 0.46405900
[10,] 0.10 42.48397  1.685719 0.09656601
```

The first column are the sigmas from 0.01 to 0.1 and for each of these I'm estimaing kappa, mu and sigma. So  row one contains estimates for sigma = 0.01, row two for sigma = 0.02 and so on.

Now take a look at row 6. Why do I get sigma = 0.07 there when it should be sigma = 0.06? And why does row 7 give me only zeros? I can't find where the logic is going wrong.

I've also printed the medians of all parameters and if I print them separately no errors are evident, but once I put them in the matrix `estimates` this happens.

Can anyone see where the error lies?

Comment: I think it has to do with floating point arithmetic: 0.06*100 could be slightly less than 7, hence row 6 is altered by the 7th round of your loop. Try adding a row with `rbind()` instead: `estimates <- rbind(estimates, c(sigma, medianKappa, medianMu, medianSigma)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing with a number that starts as a floating point number is a really bad idea, as you're seeing here. It's related to [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f), where one of your sigmas is not multiplying to an integer:

```r
seq(from = 0.01, to = 0.1, by = 0.01) * 100 == 1:10
#  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
### shown differently
options(digits = 9)
seq(from = 0.01, to = 0.1, by = 0.01) * 100 - 1:10
#  [1]  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00
#  [6]  8.8817842e-16 -8.8817842e-16  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00
```

The seventh is the culprit, since a negative there means that its real value is ever-so-slightly below the integer 7. (Kudos to Bas for identifying that.)

Note that indexing from a floating point will `trunc` the indexing value, so you can see more clearly what's going on:

```r
trunc(seq(from = 0.01, to = 0.1, by = 0.01) * 100)
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  6  8  9 10
```

This explains both why row 6 contains `0.07` (it is overwritten on the seventh iteration in the loop), and why row 7 is blank (it is never assigned).

I suggest you instead loop over the *index* of a vector of `sigma`s, something like this:

```r
  sigmas <- seq(from = 0.01, to = 0.1, by = 0.01)
  for (ind in seq_along(sigmas)){

    for (i in 1:timesteps) {

      #                                          ........... changed
      thomasSim = rThomas(kappa = kappa, scale = sigmas[ind], mu = mu, win = owin(c(0,1),c(0,1)))

      numberOfPoints[i] = thomasSim[["n"]]

      result = thomas.estK(thomasSim)

      kappaVector[i] = result$modelpar[[1]]
      sigmaVector[i] = result$modelpar[[2]]
      muVector[i] = numberOfPoints[i]/kappaVector[i]

    }

      medianSigma = median(sigmaVector)
      medianKappa = median(kappaVector)
      medianMu = median(muVector)

      #     ...........                                changed
      print(sigmas[ind])
      print(medianKappa)
      print(medianMu)
      print(medianSigma)
      print("************")

      #         ...                                    all changed
      estimates[ind,4] = medianSigma
      estimates[ind,3] = medianMu
      estimates[ind,2] = medianKappa
      #         ...      ...........                   also changed
      estimates[ind,1] = sigmas[ind]

  }
```

In this way, you can be certain that `ind` is an integer (useful for indexing), whereas you're still using the fractional value from `sigmas` that you need for the rest of your calcs.

Comment: Thank you man! Never thought of that floating point number issue.

Comment: It's a common issue with programming in general. R often does a good job just "getting it right" for you, through inference (`2 == sqrt(4)` is true) but this is imperfect (`4 == sqrt(4^4)` returns `FALSE`). The general discussion almost always returns back to IEEE-754, which generically addresses floating-point numbers on a digital processor.

Comment: Part of me wonders how productive it would be to provide a `warning` whenever indexing is done with `numeric` vice `integer` ... and then the rest of my realizes that most packages (and much of base R, I fear) makes no attempt to cast to `integer` whenever indexing a frame/matrix. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯